# How to put quote in a string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am newer in iOS. My question is how we string coming from email put in double quotes ""?

```
NSString* messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ does not apppear to be valid email address.Do You Want sent Anyway?", email];
UIAlertView *alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Invalid adress" message:messageString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alertView show];
break;
```

Comment: use this > `\"` e.g. `\"Invalid Email\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
NSString* messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"\"%@\" does not appear to be valid email address.Do You Want sent Anyway?", email];
```